# How to join two RDDs with different length in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have 2 RDDs. the first RDD is the original RDD and the second one is an RDD that i have filtered out from the original one and have done some processes on it. after performing processes i want to join them. the original RDD looks likes below:

```
(1,5)
(2,60)
(3,7)
(4,1)
(5,1)
...
(10,8)
```

and the filtered and manipulated RDD is :

```
(4,3)
(5,10)
(6,6)
(7,9)
```

how should i join them?? when i use fullouterjoin or other join methods it gives error

**Edited**

i wrote code as you said like this:

```
        original_RDD=original_RDD.fullOuterJoin(new_RDD).foreach { case (joinKey, (oldOption, newOption)) =>
        newOption match {
          case None => (joinKey,oldOption)
          case Some(newOption) => (joinKey,newOption)
        }
      }
```

but i get this error:

```
Error:(232, 55) type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, Int)]
        nodes=nodes.fullOuterJoin(joined_new).foreach { case (joinKey, (oldOption, newOption)) =>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html) join syntax

> When called on datasets of type (K, V) and (K, W), returns a dataset
>   of (K, (V, W)) pairs with all pairs of elements for each key. Outer
>   joins are supported through leftOuterJoin, rightOuterJoin, and
>   fullOuterJoin.

```
originalRdd
  .fullOuterJoin(joinRdd)
  .foreach { case (joinKey, (oldOption, newOption)) =>
    newOption match {
      case None => println("new value is None")
      case Some(joinValue) => println(s"new value = $joinValue")
    }
  }
```

Comment: i did as you said, but i got error. i have mentioned it in **Edited** part

Comment: Remove "original_RDD=". Type mismatch: original_RDD has RDD[(Long, Int)] type but foreach return Unit type. You can use "map" instead of "foreach" or whatever you want